# Why does my new bathroom light/heater/fan unit have a permanently active wire?

Tags: bathroom

Our old three in one bathroom light/heater/fan unit needed to be replaced so I bought one from Aldi. The old unit has three switches on the wall, three circuits plus earth, now the wiring diagram in the instruction booklet shows an active wire permanently connected before the bathrooms triple switch, meaning it will be live permanently. This seems wrong and as they seem definite about the fact it needs this I would like to know why? If it "does" need this wire, it is going to be a "nightmare" because the existing wires for all three existing circuits are plumbed through a brick wall, with almost no ceiling cavity access. Does it need this circuit or can it be connected the same way as the old unit, or can I use a shunt to get around the issue?
(240volt AC wiring in Australia)
Thanks guys,
Graham

Comment: Can you post a picture of the wiring diagram? And add some more information about the new unit (manufacturer and model; does it have a remote or smart features, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Many bathroom fans have a mechanism that will turn them on when the lights are turned on but only turn them off after time period from when your turn the light off. Some even have humidity sensors and will turn on automatically if the humidity rises.

In order to be able to do this you need the live feed to keep the fan running and the feed from the light to signal when the light is on.

You haven't provided a link or anything to this specific product but I would suggest that this device should still have it's own dedicated isolation switch. You'll see these above bathroom doors in UK new builds and they are typically a switch twice as wide as a normal UK light switch, often with a fan symbol on it.

I have seen people bridging the "permanant supply" and "switch supply" terminals with a wire so that they don't need to run a new cable. I can't comment on whether this is allowable or not.

Comment: Ah Ha ! OP here

Comment: This may explain why its there, so Thankyou, I bought this in Australia from "Aldi" so it could be a European thing, I have never seen the setup you describe. If it is to keep things running for a time period after its switched off, will it do any harm by just connecting it as the old one was without it present?

Comment: @BalkaRoo If it is the same setup as those sold in Europe then it shouldn't. This however is based on an assumption and not from having seen the actual product or it's instruction manual.

Comment: Thanks Scotty, I hooked it up "without" the permanently live wire, and the fan motor will not turn, you can hear that it is live but obviously needs the live wire to actually start. I have read elsewhere that they have an automatic fan turn on function if the unit overheats because someone leaves the heat lamps on without the fan, this is probably my problem. I will have a go at getting a wire in place , but it won't be easy.